# High CPU load for 1:30 minutes when mounting ext4-raid partition

Tags: mount, raid, ext4

### --> The problem solved itself <--

Sometime between November 2012 and January 2013 one of the Ubuntu updates made the time the mount command takes to complete go down to ~1 second again:

```
time mount /dev/mapper/8000 /media/8000

real    0m0.942s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.504s
```

Thanks to everyone for trying to help me out.

---

I have a raid 5 (software) with 5x2TB drives. I encrypted the raid with cryptsetup and put an ext4-partition on top.

In the beginning opening and mounting the raid took less than 10 seconds, now (for a few weeks) mounting alone takes 1:30 minutes and the cpu stays around 93% the whole time:

The output of "time sudo mount /dev/mapper/8000 /media/8000" is:

```
real    1m31.952s
user    0m0.008s
sys     1m25.229s
```

At the same time only one line is added to /var/log/syslog:

```
kernel: [ 2240.921381] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

My Ubuntu-version is "12.04.1 LTS" and no updates are pending.

I checked the partition with fsck, but it says that all is ok.

The "cryptsetup luksOpen" command only takes a few seconds.

---

I also tried changing the raid-bitmap (as it was suggested in some forum) but it did not change the behaviour.

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -b internal
```

and

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -b none
```

---

I had the idea that it might be the hardware being slow, but a read test with "sudo hdparm -t /dev/md0" spit out values between 62 and 159 MB/sec:

```
Timing buffered disk reads: 382 MB in  3.00 seconds = 127.14 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 482 MB in  3.02 seconds = 159.62 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 190 MB in  3.03 seconds =  62.65 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 474 MB in  3.02 seconds = 157.12 MB/sec
```

Although I think it is strange that the read rate jumps by more than 100% - could that mean something?

The speed test when reading from the mapped (decrypted) device shows similar behavior, although it is of course much slower. "sudo hdparm -t /dev/mapper/8000":

```
Timing buffered disk reads:  56 MB in  3.02 seconds =  18.54 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 122 MB in  3.09 seconds =  39.43 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 134 MB in  3.02 seconds =  44.35 MB/sec
```

---

The output of a verbose mount "mount -vvv /dev/mapper/8000 /media/8000" does not help much:

```
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: spec:  "/dev/mapper/8000"
mount: node:  "/media/8000"
mount: types: "(null)"
mount: opts:  "(null)"
mount: you didn't specify a filesystem type for /dev/mapper/8000
       I will try type ext4
mount: mount(2) syscall: source: "/dev/mapper/8000", target: "/media/8000", filesystemtype: "ext4", mountflags: -1058209792, data: (null)
```

---

Any idea where I could find additional information on why mounting takes so long, or what additional tests I could run?

Answer (score 0):

suggest the following exercise.

Dont mount the raid partition on boot and see what else is taking up time. If without raid its taking time then we know who is the culprit.

Comment: I am not mounting it on boot. What do you mean "without raid"?

Comment: Now I know what you mean. No, the partition on the raid is always mounted after boot (since it is encrypted by password, someone has to enter the password before it can be mounted). After the raid has been decrypted (opened with cryptsetup), the mount-command takes 1:30 minutes at 93% cpu.